# How can I use EVAL to pass arguments to subroutines?

Tags: raku

I'm experimenting with Raku and trying to figure out how I might write a program with subcommands. When I run, `./this_program blah`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env raku
use v6;

sub MAIN($cmd, *@subcommands) {
    $cmd.EVAL;
}

sub blah() { say 'running blah'; };
```

I get `running blah` output.

But this is as far as I got. I've tried various things, but I see no obvious way to pass `@subscommands` down to the `blah` function.

I'm not even sure if `EVAL` is the way to go either, but I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: OK, found the blog post at https://raku-advent.blog/2019/12/05/modular-raku-command-line-apps/ which suggests using `mutli MAIN` with literals in the arguments to create subroutines for the subcommands. However, still curious about using EVAL, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think `EVAL` isn't strictly necessary here. You can go for [indirect lookup](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#index-entry-::()), i.e.,

```
&::($cmd)(@sub-commands);
```

At the point `&::($cmd)`, the function `&blah` is looked up from the string `$cmd` and is ready to use; we then call it with `@sub-commands`.

Then we have

```
sub MAIN($cmd, *@sub-commands) {
    &::($cmd)(@sub-commands);
}

sub blah(*@args) {
    say "running `blah` with `{@args}`";
}
```

and running as

```
$ raku ./program blah this and that
```

gives

```
running `blah` with `this and that`
```

Answer (score 6):

Making `MAIN` a multi could also be a solution:

```
multi sub MAIN('blah', *@rest) {
    say "running blah with: @rest[]";
}
multi sub MAIN('frobnicate', $this) {
    say "frobnicating $this";
}
```

Comment: What an amazing language... Did you mean `@rest[]` or `{@rest}` or probably-some-other-way-that-I-don't-know-because-Raku-is-amazing :)

Comment: @Neither I meant `@rest[]`  :-)    Fixed